# Navbar logo link css

Tags: css

I am trying to make the "alt" text of the brand-logo and brand-logo-collapsed  link white instead of the default blue like all the other ones. But am unable to figure out the proper css to specifically call that portion. Will someone please guide me in the correct direction.

```
<a href="#/" class="navbar-brand">
                  <div class="brand-logo">
                     <img src="#" alt="Dealer Tracking" class="img-responsive">           
                  </div>
                  <div class="brand-logo-collapsed">
                     <img src="#" alt="Dealer Tracking" class="img-responsive">   
                  </div>
               </a>
```

CSS

```
a > navbar-brand > img {
  color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: `a.navbar-brand img { color: white; }` There are a few ways if you wanted to get more specific, or use a wildcard to select any class like "brand-logo", but this should do it.

Comment: What do you mean by style the "alt" text? If you want the text that shows up within the img tag when there is no src, this is how you would do it. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zZZQbq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your element with `navbar-brand` class is the same element as the anchor, so need to be treated as such in the CSS (be removing the space in between). Also classnames should be prepended with a `.`, and as you have a `div` in between the image and the anchor, it will break the rule, as `>` only selected direct descendants, so get rid of that:

```
a.navbar-brand img {
color: #fff;
}
```

Should get it working.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
.brand-logo > img, .brand-logo-collapsed img{
   color: white;
}
```

And if you want to to this for all of your images:

```
img{
   color: white;
}
```